# running rails 3.1.1 on windows as a service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

My goal is to run a rails 3.1.1 app as a service on a windows box that is accessible to a local intranet.

if it isn't possible to run as a service, what would be the preferred method to run my rails app?

advice/suggestions/opinions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [mongrel_service](http://rubygems.org/gems/mongrel_service) gem, which currently offers the simplest solution. It wraps mongrel in a service.

But i also wrote a [blogpost](http://www.dixis.com/?p=140) how to create a service using thin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried using the steps you detailed in your blog post to make a thin service, but every time I try to start the service it exits immediately (the error message says something about nothing being connected to the service).  The same commands for running the thin server work fine at the command prompt.